# VSTS Build jobs freeze sporadically

Tags: azure-devops

using visual studio team services online with an in house build agent. The build agent while running a job will randomly just freeze, the job is still active but there are no updates to the console, not errors in event logs etc. If I open the agent's _diag folder and look it will just repeat what is below until it decides to continue work.

```
17:02:19.850546 LogFileTimer_Callback - enter (20)
 17:02:19.850546 LogFileTimer_Callback - processing job 7b9229d0-524e-4138-b6b3-33f630d109c6
 17:02:19.850546 LogFileTimer_Callback - found 0 records for job 7b9229d0-524e-4138-b6b3-33f630d109c6
 17:02:19.850546 LogFileTimer_Callback - leave
 17:02:20.100159 StatusTimer_Callback - enter (27)
 17:02:20.100159 StatusTimer_Callback - processing job 7b9229d0-524e-4138-b6b3-33f630d109c6
 17:02:20.100159 StatusTimer_Callback - leave
 17:02:20.240566 ConsoleTimer_Callback - enter (17)
 17:02:20.240566 ConsoleTimer_Callback - Inside Lock
 17:02:20.240566 ConsoleTimer_Callback - processing job 7b9229d0-524e-4138-b6b3-33f630d109c6
 17:02:20.240566 ConsoleTimer_Callback - leave
 17:02:20.755392 ConsoleTimer_Callback - enter (22)
 17:02:20.755392 ConsoleTimer_Callback - Inside Lock
 17:02:20.755392 ConsoleTimer_Callback - processing job 7b9229d0-524e-4138-b6b3-33f630d109c6
 17:02:20.755392 ConsoleTimer_Callback - leave
 17:02:20.864598 StatusTimer_Callback - enter (18)
 17:02:20.864598 StatusTimer_Callback - processing job 7b9229d0-524e-4138-b6b3-33f630d109c6
 17:02:20.864598 StatusTimer_Callback - leave
```

We have tried deleting the work folder, uninstalling the agent and reinstalling and it still just seems to freeze on random jobs. Any idea what else I could look into as why this is happening?

Comment: Will your build fail when this phenomenon occur? What kind of tasks will have this phenomenon?

Comment: If we wait it out, the builds will be fine ... sometimes this even occurs on releases too. So, a build job that normally takes 3 minutes ... if we wait 15ish it will finish

Answer (score 0):

Just checked one log, and found these information existed in the log file here and there. Such as restore packages, upload logs, or retrieve files, etc.

These information don't mean there is an error. You may try to create a new agent on another machine to see whether this phenomenon would occur.

Comment: I will try installing the agent on another machine but I was hoping for more troubleshooting tips that I could use to help diagnose this machine. It doesn't seem to be a resource problem, the server is doing nothing while the job is also doing nothing.

Comment: As there is no error message, it's hard for us to troubleshoot this phenomenon. Try with another machine to monitor it.